# Dual-boot Ubuntu Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have a problem during installation of Ubuntu. After I select "Install alongside with Windows 10" and press "Continue" my laptop restarts and boots Windows 10. So i never get to install Ubuntu and I don't know why...

Comment: There is not enough information here about what is happening for us to even guess. Please provide more information.

Comment: So, I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10. The installation doesn't start because my laptop restarts and boots Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have secure Boot enabled. Try to disable it. If the setup of Ubuntu does not work for you try the Boot repair Disc and let your Boot Problem get fixed automatically:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

I cannot recommend this thing enough. It is awesome! It can handle both Legacy BIOS and UEFI.

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you give me a tip to use it? and thanks for suggestion

Comment: I did use boot repair and it messed up my laptop, i can't even access Windows...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boot order within your BIOS, so it boots the Ubuntu Installation media after the restart